# How to upload images from the client side?

Tags: html, css

how do I make a field that the client can send images to the database as if it were text?

`<label for="email"><b>name</b></label>`
`<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" name="email" id="name" requir`#the code to input text

but there is a similar way to input images?

Answer (score 0):

A [file input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file) element will allow a file (including an image file) to be submitted in an HTTP request.

The form element will need to be configured to encode data in the `multipart/form-data` format.

```
<form action="example" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">Select image</label>
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file">
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

How you handle this on the server will depend on the server-side language you are using.

As a rule of thumb, binary data like images are generally best stored on a file system or on a service like Amazon S3 and not placed directly in the database.